How to prevent rows from scrolling into NSTableView column header row
When scrolling rows of data in an NSTableView with a column header row with a clear background, the top row of data moves up and instead of disappearing completely it appears faintly behind the column header. In the image below, the top row has an ID of 2000 and a name of Johnny Carson. As the row scrolls up, the data is dimmed and is behind the column name. How can this behavior be prevented so the data does not appear behind the header?

I tried adjusting a constraint but it did not work.
func adjustTableViewConstraints() {
       guard let scrollView = tableview.enclosingScrollView else { return }
       
       // Adjust the contentInsets of the scroll view to account for the header view height
       let headerHeight = tableview.headerView?.frame.height ?? 0
       scrollView.contentInsets = NSEdgeInsets(top: headerHeight, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
   }

